# What is the zsh idiom for using functions that can return success or failure as well as a list

Tags: function, zsh, idioms

I am looking for the "best way" or the accepted zsh idiom for creating and using functions that can return success or failure as well as a list or other text value.

Currently I am doing this:

```
function happy
{
    local happy_list=( a b c d )

    if true ; then
        echo $happy_list
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

function sad
{
    local sad_list=( a b c d )

    if false ; then
        echo $sad_list
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

echo happy
if happy_result=( $( happy ) ) ; then
    echo '$?:' $?
    echo '$#happy_result' $#happy_result
    echo '$happy_result' $happy_result
    echo '$happy_list:' $happy_list
else
    echo '!?!?!?!?'
fi

echo
echo sad
if sad_result=( $( sad ) ) ; then
    echo '!?!?!?!?'
else
    echo '$?:' $?
    echo '$#sad_result' $#sad_result
    echo '$sad_result:' $sad_result
    echo '$sad_list:' $sad_list
fi
```

which results in

```
happy
$?: 0
$#happy_result 4
$happy_result a b c d
$happy_list:

sad
$?: 1
$#sad_result 0
$sad_result:
$sad_list:
```

Is there a cleaner method?  In particular the `foo=( $( func ) )` syntax seems it could be improved since the list is already created in the func.

Update to moderator: I believe now this is a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535118/82474) and my preferred answer (if anyone cares) is [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537981/82474).  The suggestion in Meta was to close and merge.  I don't know how to do the merge.  Can a moderator help me out?

Comment: All functions return success or failure, and it's the *only* thing they can return. All other types of communication is via file descriptors or global variables. ("Function" is really a pretty terrible name for this shell construct, but one we are stuck with for historical reasons.)

Comment: Keep in mind that the reason arrays exist is the same reason why `( $(happy) )` is not a safe way to create an array in the first place.

Comment: My *preferred* idiom is to avoid writing functions that "return" values in the first place.

Comment: Unix shells tend toward a functional programming style, probably because of pipes, text as a universal interface, and quickly composing one off scripts. `echo "$output"` works ok when you want to chain functions and programs together as filters in a pipeline. Instead of command substitution you might want: `happy | xargs do-foo`, to convert stdin to arguments. If you really need/want a variable, you can also just set a global variable (or array) in the function, by skipping `local`.

Comment: I've continued surfing and so far, my favorite solution is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537981/82474).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual idiom in `zsh` is to return scalar results in the `$REPLY` variable and array results in the `$reply` array:

```
all-files-in() {
  reply=( $^@/*(ND) )
  (( $#reply ))
}

if all-files-in /foo /bar; then
  print -r there were files: $reply
else
  print -ru2 there were none
fi
```

Another approach is for the caller to specify the name of the variable where to store the result and use `eval` or the `P` parameter expansion flag to do indirect assignments.

```
all-files-in() {
  eval $1='( $^@[2,-1]/*(ND) )
  (( $#'$1' ))'
}

if all-files-in files /foo /bar; then
  print -r there were files: $files
else
  print -ru2 there were none
fi
```